# Module does not support count

Tags: terraform

I am trying to create a dynamic resources through a module using `count`.
However, the usage of count is giving me following error:

```
Error: Module does not support count

  on server_gx_custom_dynamic.tf line 8, in module "server_gx_custom_dynamic":
   8:   count = len(var.units_wp3)

Module "server_gx_custom_dynamic" cannot be used with count because
it contains a nested provider configuration for "grafana", at
modules  server_gx/custom/custom.tf:11,10-19.

This module can be made compatible with count by changing it to receive all of
its provider configurations from the calling module, by using the "providers"
argument in the calling module block.
```

I did try to add provider configurations in child module also but of no use, same error (of course I didn't do it right). Where can I start with this issue?

Without the introduction of count my modules works perfectly.

```
`server_gx_custom_dynamic.tf`
module "server_gx_custom_dynamic" {
  count = len(var.units_wp3)

  source = "./modules/server_gx/custom"

    ...
}

`./modules/server_gx/custom/custom.tf`

resource "grafana_monitor" "custom_monitor" {
  name = ...

    ...
}
```

Comment: Which version of Terraform are you using, as using the count meta-argument with modules is only supported in Terraform 0.13 or later.
https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/count.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message appears because module `server_gx_custom_dynamic` includes a local provider configuration, rather than just inheriting provider configurations from the calling module.

The error message includes a reference to the location of that provider configuration, which appears as `modules  server_gx/custom/custom.tf:11,10-19` here. At that location I expect you'll find a `provider "grafana"` block.

To make this configuration `count`-compatible you'll need to remove that provider block. If your root module already contains a `provider "grafana"` block then just removing that nested provider configuration might be sufficient to make it work, because by default Terraform will make a default (unaliased) provider configuration from the root module available to all child modules.

In more complicated situations where you have multiple configurations for the same provider you'll need to use "additional" (aliased) provider configurations. Those are represented as `provider` blocks containing the special `alias` argument. Additional provider blocks don't automatically inherit in the way that default provider configurations do, and so you'd need to use an explicit `providers` argument inside the `modules` block in that case.

There's more information on this mechanism in the documentation page [Providers Within Modules](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/develop/providers.html). In particular, your module is currently in the situation described in the section [Legacy Shared Modules with Provider Configurations](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/develop/providers.html#legacy-shared-modules-with-provider-configurations), which includes some additional context about the problem along with some examples on how to address it.

Answer (score 0):

In the module that contains `resource "grafana_monitor" "custom_monitor"` there should be a provider.tf or even just a provider block of code. Try to remove that completely from the module that contains the resource block and move it into `module "server_gx_custom_dynamic"`. See how that works.

Alternatively you could try to introduce count into the child module that contains `resource "grafana_monitor" "custom_monitor"`. I am not sure if this will work as intended if the provider block is still in that child module but could be something to try out.

When you say you added the provider configuration into the child module are you referring to the directory that has `./modules/server_gx/custom/custom.tf`?